# Checking Unique Key is Composite Key or not in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Working with SQL Server:

```
Alter Table <table_name> Add Constraint <Constraint_Name> Unique (<Column1,Column2>)
```

I make a unique key constraint on my table and this unique key is made up of 2 columns, i.e. `column1` and `column2`.

If I have `Constraint_Name`, then is there any way to find this constraint is composite or not, and if composite then from which columns it is made?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  <table_name>
WHERE <column1> = <something> AND <column2> = <something_else>
```

Yes this will be a composite key, because it is *composed* of more than 1 column.
[MSDN Primer on Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/primary-and-foreign-key-constraints)

Answer (score 0):

You can join [`sys.indexes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-indexes-transact-sql) and [`sys.index_columns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-index-columns-transact-sql) together based on `object_id` and `index_id`. You use the constraint name to match the name in `sys.indexes`. The number of result rows returned will tell you how many columns are in the index, so a single-row result is on one column, a multi-row result is a multi-column index.

The example on the `sys.index_columns` page shows how to use the `COL_NAME` function to translate back to the column names, or alternatively you can join to `sys.columns` to get that data back.

(Unique key constraints are implemented as unique indexes with the same name)